# RegEx pattern with not followed by

Tags: regex

I want to match only first file path, which not contains word Thumbnails. I use "not-followed by pattern" but it doesn`t work. Could some one take a look and tell me where is my mistake? Here is my regex:

```
<string>((.*(?!Thumbnails))\.jpg)</string>
```

Strings

```
<string>/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters/2012/05/14/20120514-105314/IMG_6204.JPG</string>
<string>/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Thumbnails/2012/05/14/20120514-105314/IMG_6204.jpg</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp will match file paths which do not contain "Thumbnails" *right before the file extension*. You want to prevent it from matching those which contain "Thumbnails" *anywhere* in the text.

You could try something like:

```
<string>((?!.*Thumbnails).*?\.jpg)</string>
```

Or:

```
<string>((?![^<]*Thumbnails)[^<]*\.jpg)</string>
```

(That will prevent the regexp engine from going past the closing "<" when searching for "Thumbnails". It will also disallow file paths which contain "<".)

I presume you are matching this against individual lines of text, *not* against a string which contains multiple lines, right?

Comment: Thank you, it`s works perfect.
Yes, I`m matching strings which contains 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<string>^((?!Thumbnails).)*$</string>
```

Comment: Yes. Probably because I originally wrote "<strong>" instead of "<string>"? :)

Comment: The `^` and `$` are also not needed. Or if you do want them, they should go at the very beginning and end of the regexp. (`<string>` can't appear *before* the beginning of the line.) Also, you need to explicitly match the `.jpg` suffix which the OP expects.